# Fashion photography mini studio

Tags: studio, fashion

If I wanted to start a mini studio for fashion photography, what equipment will I be needing as basics?

Comment: Equipment is a personal choice and varies from person to person. We can't suggest cameras or lenses here. But if you have any doubts about specific equipment compatibility, we can answer that.

Comment: Voting to close. Equipment recommendations are off topic, this is an overly broad and opinion based question (I could say beauty dish, someone else could say big softbox (technical term). Neither answers are wrong. But provide entirely different results) and not enough information, e.g. size, is it a home studio or commercial. If commercial will it be rented?

Comment: *Specific* equipment recommendations (i.e. Brand C vs. Brand N) are off topic. General recommendations as to what *type* of equipment might be needed for a particular type of photo are not off topic. E.g. "What qualities should one look for in a lens for astrophotography" is on topic. "What is the best lens for astrophotography" or "What lens should I buy" is not.

Comment: As asked, though, the question is awfully broad.

Answer (score 1):

You would need at the very basic level:

A working camera including a lens.
A source of light.
Enough space to allow your camera to focus on your subjects.
A subject to shoot.

All else is optional.